T-SQL: remove ending characters from table
My table contains values like this
Name
______
Name(122)
anotherName(12312)
Another2Name(12321) 
Name(2)Name(123213)

I would like them to appear like this:
Name
______
Name
anotherName
Another2Name 
Name(2)Name

How could I create a query or update the table to remove the ending (###).
Any help with this would be great.
I've tried a few methods where I remove everything after a bracket but some of the values have brackets in the name.
Another method I tried was removing all numeric values but then you have the example where a number is in the name like Another2Name.

"I've tried a few methods ..."  Where???  We don't see a single query in this post.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Please try the following solution based on the TRIM() function functionality.
TRIM (Transact-SQL)
It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _name varchar(200));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('Name(122)'),
('anotherName(12312)'),
('Another2Name(12321)'), 
('Name(2)Name(123213)');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , TRIM('()0123456789' FROM _name) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t;

Output



ID
_name
result




1
Name(122)
Name


2
anotherName(12312)
anotherName


3
Another2Name(12321)
Another2Name


4
Name(2)Name(123213)
Name(2)Name




This is how you can get the last index of something:
select right([Name], charindex('(', reverse([Name]) + '_') - 1) from yourtable

And this is how you can select a substring:
SELECT SUBSTRING([Name], 1, right([Name], charindex('(', reverse([Name]) + '_') - 1)) AS ExtractString from yourtable;

And this is how you can update to it:
update yourtable set [Name] = SUBSTRING([Name], 1, right([Name], charindex('(', reverse([Name]) + '_') - 1))

Untested, let me know if there were typos on my part.

The output of this:
select * 
from string_split('Name(2)Name(123213)','(') 
where right(value,1)=')';

is 123213)
When using that on your table you can do:
UPDATE mytable
SET name = replace(name,
                   concat('(',(select * 
                               from string_split(name,'(') 
                               where right(value,1)=')')),
                   '');

which is replacing the piece found in the first query, preceded by a (, with a space.
NOTE:  This solution has, 1 known, problem. That is when name has a ) immediately before the )  (For example test(42)(123)).  this is because the first query in this answer will return more than 1 result, when this happens...
see: DBFIDDLE

Using a reverse-charindex-reverse trick:
Select 
[tt]
From @Tbl
Outer apply (select isnull([name],'') 
[t])t
Outer apply (select 
reverse(substring(reverse([t]),
charindex(' 
(',reverse([t]),1)+1,100))[tt])tt

(Aliases used: [name] -> [t] -> [tt])
Explanation, step by step:
-> 'text(1234)'
reverse
-> ')4321(txet'
charindex('(',')4321(txet',1)
-> 6
substring(')4321(txet',6+1,100)
-> 'txet'
reverse
-> 'text'

Isnull is used because charindex doesn't handle null values well.

How does this relate to the original data? The formatting and aliases are so difficult to read and the columns and table are the same as the question. Also, code only answers are rarely good as they usually need some explanation.

Thanks for the notificaton, is it better with the fixes?
